# Query data after hitting the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to figure out how to pull a set of data and then manipulate it afterwards, instead of querying the database as and when I require data. I am building a dashboard and this is required for performance reasons.

To dumb down the example as much as possible, lets say you want to pull all users

```
users = User.all
```

Then you want to filter that data, but you want to do it after all the data has been pulled

```
my_users = users.where(is_admin: true)
```

I know the previous line isn't the correct syntax for what I am looking for, but I want something to that affect that will query the preloaded data stored in the users variable.

Do I convert the active relation to an array and cycle through the array looking at each item? For example should I do this

```
users.to_ary.reject{|u| u[:is_admin] == true }
```

or something to that affect?

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`my_user = User.all.to_array.keep_if{|u| u.is_admin == true}`
I think is the best way of doing it.